# Can I start Apache spark remotely from my Eclipse? Inner classes trigger ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

So, I have an Apache Spark cluster running on a server with one master and a few workers.

Now I want to run my application from Eclipse on this server. When i run my program locally everything is fine and it works. As soon as i try to connect to the spark-master-node of the cluster, I get a ClassNotFoundException. Apparently Spark cannot find the inner classes of my program, especially the DBConnection.class. Inside of this class I create a connection to a database. Might the problem here be, that the Spark Server does not know the needed driver? The driver is imported to the Eclipse project.

```
private static final SparkContext sc =
    new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbc").setMaster
             ("spark://<masternode-ip>:7077"));


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection(MYDB_DRIVER, 
             MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PWD);
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    .
    .
    .

}

    public DbConnection(String driverClassName, String connectionUrl, 
        String userName, String password) {
        this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
        this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

The ClassNotFoundException triggers on the DbConnection class.

The question now is: Is it even possible to run applications remotely directly out of Eclipse in this situation? And how do the workers know what they have to do? Or is the only solution here to create a JAR file and run this one on the server?

Comment: yes you will have to make a jar and submit it remotely. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I expected something like this, was just hoping there would be a faster way.